# Генератор случайных чисел с энтропией

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, qt4

Необходимо сгенерировать случайные числа  в диапазоне от 0 до 100 с шагом 1 (или 0..1 с шагом 0.01), причем с нормированной разницей/погрешностью (отклонение от равномерного распределения) не более 0,1 (т.е. разброс количества повторов не более 10% между минимальным и максимальным количеством) при достаточно небольшом общем количестве (скажем, всего 20000 случайных чисел).

Через `rand()`, соответственно, не выйдет, думаю насчет использования энтропии, `random_device`, увы, не подходит, т.к. и под `Windows` должно работать. Использую `C++11`, `gcc 4.8`, `Qt 4.8`, `MinGW32`.

При использовании функции
`CryptGenRandom` нормированная разница около 0,6.

Comment: а в чем проблема random_device под Windows?

Comment: Что это за термин - "нормированная разница"? Что такое минимальное количество повторов?

Comment: Почему-то так получилось, что я первый раз вижу эти термины, их не было ни в курсе тервера, ни у Кнута. Вы уверены что пользуетесь общепринятыми терминами?

Comment: Начните со статической генерации минимального постоянного фона (скажем, при 20к чисел от 0 до 100 и норме в 10% это будет по 180 чисел). А уже остаток в 1820 чисел - генерируйте рандомно, следя за нормой и выбрасывая генерации, выпадающие за верхний порог. Если нужно ещё и равномерное распределение по массиву, а не только сам массив - после генерации выполните его случайное перемешивание.

Comment: @b2soft в Windows с mingw random_device каждый раз выдает одни и те же значения, т.к. энтропия = 0. Возможно, эту проблему можно обойти?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov нормированная разница = нормированная погрешность. Максимум ( количество) минус минимум делить на максимум. Для каждого из чисел после N генераций получается количество, сколько раз было сгенерированно это число. И отсюда из всех количеств находятся минимум и максимум. Т.е. по сути нужно максимально приблизиться к равномерному распределению.

Comment: @Laa погрешность **чего**? У ГСЧ не может быть погрешности потому что он ничего не измеряет.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov это уже углубление в теорию и отдаление от сути задачи. Погрешность, насколько я помню, это отклонение от необходимого/требуемого/истинного значения, не суть. Необходимо/требуется в данном случае равномерное распределение

Comment: @Laa все современные ГСЧ выдают равномерное распределение, других не бывает.

Comment: @Laa я никуда не отдаляюсь, а пытаюсь понять что вы пытаетесь сделать и в чем заключается ваша задача

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov равномерное, но в той или иной степени, насколько я понимаю. 
Равномерное - когда вероятность выпадения того или иного числа равновероятна. Т.е., грубо говоря, из N случайных чисел в диапазоне a-b каждое число выпадет N/(a-b) раз, ни больше, ни меньше. Проблема сейчас состоит в том, что для всех трёх ГПСЧ/ГСЧ отклонение от этой равномерности слишком большое.

Comment: @Laa вам следует выучить теорию вероятностей хотя бы в общих чертах. Равномерным распределением называют вполне конкретное распределение, которое имеет мало общего с названным вами.

Comment: @Laa я просмотрел интернет насчет проблемы, действительно, random_device в MinGW правильно не реализован. Попробуйте использовать конкретный девайс: `std::mt19937 gen; gen.seed (time (0)); `

Answer (score 5):

Все современные ГСЧ имеют равномерное распределение, других не бывает (точнее, их быстро исправляют, отклонение от равномерного распределения - это серьезный баг).

Когда вы N раз равномерно выбираете одно из M значений - число выборов каждого значения подчиняется [биноминальному распределению](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) с параметрами N, 1/M.

Интересующее вас значение, которое вы называете погрешностью, можно грубо *оценить* как отношение среднеквадратического отклонения к матожиданию (эта оценка очень не точная, но она использует довольно простые формулы и дает представление о порядке искомой величины).

Математическое ожидание для такого распределения равно N/M, а cреднеквадратическое отклонение этого распределения равно квадратному корню из N/M*(1 - 1/M). Отношение среднеквадратического отклонения к матожиданию равно квадратному корню из M/N*(1 - 1/M) = (M-1)/N. При M=100 и N=20000 это будет примерно 0.07, что довольно похоже на ваши результаты для CryptGenRandom.

---

Таким образом, равномерное распределение вам не подходит. Если вам нужно чтобы все числа встречались в выходной последовательности примерно одинаковое количество раз - придется отказаться от независимой генерации элементов последовательности.

Так, для ограниченной последовательности вы можете взять массив, заполнить его нужными числами, после чего сгенерировать [**случайную перестановку**](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8,_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0) этого массива.

Альтернативный вариант - считать сколько каких чисел было сгенерировано и после генерации каждого числа на основе этих данных пересчитывать распределение вероятностей для следующего числа.

Тут вам поможет алгоритм генерации случайного числа с табличным распределением.